# Union of a strictly increasing sequence of closed theories in a finite language has an infinite model

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

> The union of a strictly increasing sequence of closed theories in a finite language has an infinite model.

This is an exercise in the book by Chang-Keisler. I don't have any idea to prove it. I just know that the union of a strictly increasing sequence of closed theories is a consistent closed theory which is not finitely axiomatizable, and also that the model of the union of consistent increasing theories is also the model of each theory.
If the union was complete the problem would be solved.

Comment: *Hint:* use ultraproduct.

Comment: Ultra product? How?

Comment: What is a "closed" theory?  Does that just mean deductively closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't want to give away the whole problem, but here are a couple hints to get started:

- First, show that if $\Sigma$ is a finite language then for each $n$ there are only finitely many $\Sigma$-structures of cardinality $\le n$ (up to isomorphism). *In fact, more is true: every finite $\Sigma$-structure is characterized up to isomorphism by a single $\Sigma$-sentence. This isn't needed here, though.*
- Next, remember that by the compactness theorem, if a theory has arbitrarily large finite models then it has infinite models.
- So suppose $(T_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an increasing sequence of  closed theories such that $T:=\bigcup T_i$ has no infinite model. Then some $T_i$ satisfies "there are at most $n$ elements in the domain" for some $n$; in particular, by the first bulletpoint there is some finite set of structures $\{\mathcal{M}_1,...,\mathcal{M}_k\}$ such that every model of $T_i$ is isomorphic to one of the $\mathcal{M}_j$s.
- Now, suppose $S_2$ is a closed theory properly containing $S_1$. What can you say about the set of models of $S_2$ versus the set of models of $S_1$? Looking back to the previous bulletpoint, what does this say about any increasing sequence $(T_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of closed theories whose union has no infinite models?

Comment: I can't understand in step three why we have such a finite set ?

Comment: And why some $T_i$  satisfies that sentence? Is the union complete?

Comment: @user470412 Re: your first comment, that's *exactly* what the first bulletpoint says: if $T_i$ satisfies "there are at most $n$ elements in the domain," then every model of $T_i$ has cardinality $\le n$, and by the first bulletpoint there are only finitely many such structures (up to isomorphism).

Comment: Re: your second comment, no, the theory is not assumed to be complete. However, by the second bulletpoint we know that if the union has arbitrarily large models it has infinite models. Since we're assuming the union has *no* infinite models, this means there is a bound on the size of the finite models - that is (since $T$, being a union of a chain of closed theories, is closed), for some $n$ the sentence "there are at most $n$ elements in the domain" is in $T$. Now do you see why anything in $T$ is also in one of the $T_i$s?

Comment: In step2 you mean every model of $S_2$ is a model of $S_1$ ? And every model of the union is a model of each $T_i$, so each $T_i$ has at least one finite model. I don't know how to use this....

Comment: @user470412 "In step2 you mean every model of $S_2$ is a model of $S_1$." That's not *all* I mean. You can say a bit more, since $S_2$ **properly** extends $S_1$ ... *(This will use the fact that $S_1$ is closed.)* (cont'd)

Comment: "And every model of the union is a model of each $T_i$, so each $T_i$ has at least one finite model." That's true, but not relevant. Let's go slower: do you see why there must be a finite bound on the models of $T$ (where $T=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} T_i$)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80197/discussion-between-noah-schweber-and-user470412).

Comment: (Sorry, two comments ago should read "there must be a finite bound on the **sizes of** models of $T$". My bad.)

Comment: No i really don't get it so sorry....  I even don't kno why the first bulletpoint is true....

Comment: @user468730 Alright, let's discuss that in chat. (And, are you the same person as user470412?)